# Problem using multiple CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create an SQL that added two more conditions when the specific column(value) is matched.

Example:

```sql
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE 
    NAME_COLUMN = 'NAME'
    AND
    CASE
        WHEN AGE = '18'
        THEN ADULTHOOLD_COLUMN
    END = 1
    AND
    CASE
        WHEN AGE = '18'
        THEN ADULTHOOLD_COLUMN_1
    END = 1
```

It is working when `AGE = 18` it will return value that `ADULTHOOLD_COLUMN = 1` and `ADULTHOOLD_COLUMN_1 = 1`

but when age is not equal to 18 it will not return any rows.
I was expecting that all of the data(with 1 or 0) will return.
`ADULTHOOLD_COLUMN(Value in db is 1 or 0)`
`ADULTHOOLD_COLUMN_1(Value in db is 1 or 0)`

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING and it's [ANNOYING](https://twitter.com/PHP_CEO).

Comment: Just wondering, is `ADULTHOOLD` a spelling mistake of `ADULTHOOD`?

Comment: yes just a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit strange, but ok, looks like you need `else`:

```sql
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE 
    NAME_COLUMN = 'NAME'
    AND
    CASE
        WHEN AGE = '18'
        THEN ADULTHOOD_COLUMN
        ELSE 1
    END = 1
    AND
    CASE
        WHEN AGE = '18'
        THEN ADULTHOOD_COLUMN_1
        ELSE 1
    END = 1
```

Or maybe just to make it more readable:

```sql
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE 
     NAME_COLUMN = 'NAME'
 AND (AGE is null OR AGE!='18' OR AGE = '18' AND ADULTHOOD_COLUMN = 1)
 AND (AGE is null OR AGE!='18' OR AGE = '18' AND ADULTHOOD_COLUMN_1 = 1)
```

PS. Are you sure that `AGE` is not number? If that's a number datatype, you need to replace `'18'` to `18`